# php link with variable #test

Tags: php, parallax

I have a page works with parallax, so everything works fine in one page.

But i need creat a variable into the link, for example.

I have this and works fine withou the variable,

```
<li><a href="#second">PRODUCTS</a>
```

I try this with the variable but dont work.

```
<li><a href="#second&page=1">PRODUCTS</a>
```

If i do this the parallax dont work and the link dont work to.

Now i do it with javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 1; 
</script>

<li><a href="#second" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+scrt_var;return false;">PRODUCTS</a>
```

The url stay

```
site/#bamboo?key=1
```

But now i cant print in the php,

```
echo $_GET[$key]
```

Comment: Remove the `#` if you want to perform an actual request.

Comment: But if i remove the # i go to other page... and my site works all in one page...